# Remove numbers at beginning of filenames in directory in bash

Tags: bash, rename, filenames

In an attempt to rename the files in one directory with numbers at the front I made an error in my script so that this happened in the wrong directory. Therefore I now need to remove these numbers from the beginning of all of my filenames in a directory. These range from 1 to 3 digits. Examples of the filnames I am working with are:

```
706terrain_Slope1000m_Minimum_all_25PCs_bolt_all_25PCs_qq_bolt.png
680met_sfcWind_all_25PCs_bolt_number.txt
460greenness_NDVI_500m_min_all_25PCs_bolt_number.txt
```

I was thinking of using mv but I'm not really sure how to do it with varying numbers of digits at the beginning, so any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way in bash is making use of a regular expression test:

```sh
for file in *; do
    [[ -f "${file}" ]] && [[ "${file}" =~ (^[0-9]+) ]] && mv ${file} ${file/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}}
done
```

This does the following:

- **`[[ -f "${file}" ]]`:** test if `file` is a file, if so
- **`[[ "${file}" =~ (^[0-9]+) ]]`:** check if file starts with a number
- **`${file/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}}`:** remove the number from the string `file` by using `BASH_REMATCH`, a variable that matches the groupings from the regex match.

Answer (score 2):

Using `bash` parameter expansion:

```
shopt -s extglob
for i in +([0-9])*.{txt,png}; do 
   mv -- "$i" "${i##+([0-9])}"
done
```

This will remove starting digits (any number) in filenames having `png` and `txt` extension.

The `##` is removing the longest matching prefix pattern.

The `+(...)` is path name expansion syntax for repeated characters.

And `[0-9]` is pattern matching digits.

Comment: Or alternatively use `./*.txt ./*.png` in the globs. This is to take care of the edge case where a file has a name that `mv` could mistake for an option.

Comment: You need `shopt -s extglob` for the group quantifier `+` to work. Also it is good practice to terminate `mv` options with `--`, like this: `mv -- "$i" "${i##+([0-9])}"`. Finally to avoid iterating files who don't need a rename, you can iterate on `for i in +([[:digit:]])*.+(txt|png); do`

Comment: You also need `shopt -s nullglob` or it will fail if no file match the globbing because without `nullglob` it returns the pattern itself as a result.

Comment: always be careful if your glob matches nothing, this could become ugly very fast.

Answer (score 2):

Using basic features of a POSIX-compliant shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in [[:digit:]]*; do
  if [ -f "$f" ]; then
    pf="${f%${f#???}}" pf="${pf##*[[:digit:]]}"
    mv "$f" "$pf${f#???}"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've got `perl`'s `rename` installed, the following should work :

```
rename 's/^[0-9]{1,3}//' /path/to/files
```

`/path/to/files` can be a list of specific files, or probably in your case a glob (e.g. `*.{png,txt}`). You don't need to select only files starting with digits as `rename` won't modify those that do not.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate method using GNU `find`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

find ./ \
 -maxdepth 1\
 -type f\
 -name '[[:digit:]]*'\
 -exec bash -c 'shopt -s extglob; f="${1##*/}"; d="${1%%/*}"; mv -- "$1" "${d}/${f##+([[:digit:]])}"' _ {} \;
```

Find all actual files in current directory whose name start with a digit.

For each found file, execute the Bash script below:

```sh
shopt -s extglob # need for extended pattern syntax
f="${1##*/}" # Get file name without directory path
d="${1%%/*}" # Get directory path without file name
mv -- "$1" "${d}/${f##+([[:digit:]])}" # Rename without the leading digits
```